# Jmx client throwing InstanceNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, client, classpath, jmx

I have a Jmx Client that i use to test a jmx bean I've written. Here's the code for the client:

```
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8686/jmxrmi");
    JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);

    MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
    ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("com.spmsoftware.processing.ping:type=ProcessingPing");

    ProcessingPing mbeanProxy = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mbsc, mbeanName, ProcessingPing.class, true);
    System.out.println("\nResult = " + mbeanProxy.ping(346, 0).getResultCode());

    jmxc.close();
```

ProcessingPing and all it's dependencies are present in a library in IntelliJ.

My jmx beans are:

```
    public interface ProcessingPing {

        public PingResult ping(Integer environmentId, Integer timeout);
    }
```

and

```
    @Service("ProcessingPing")
    @ManagedResource(description = "")
    public class ProcessingPingImpl implements ProcessingPing {

        private static final Integer DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 5000;

        @Autowired
        private PingProcessService pingProcessService;

        @Override
        @ManagedOperation(description = "")
        public PingResult ping(Integer environmentId, Integer timeout) {
            return pingProcessService.run(environmentId, timeout);
        }            
    }
```

When running, the client, i get an exception when trying to invoke the ping method:

```
    Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: com.spmsoftware.processing.ping:type=ProcessingPing
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getClassLoaderFor(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1444)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getClassLoaderFor(JmxMBeanServer.java:1308)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor.getClassLoaderFor(DynamicInterceptor.java:907)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$4.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1346)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getClassLoaderFor(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1342)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:795)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:1017)
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56621', transport: 'socket'
        at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:305)
        ... 2 more
```

I do not understand why jmx seems to be able to get the bean, but not the actual instance of the class. I am guessing it's sort of a classpath issue, but couldn't find it. As a side not, when testing with JConsole, it works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the object name used to register the MBean differs from the object name you use when trying to retrieve the managed bean.

Try to check the object name in JConsole.

Comment: You mean, "processingPing" vs "ProcessingPing"? Yeah, that was a typo, but i get the same exception after changing it.

Comment: I actually meant the whole object name - "com.spmsoftware.processing.ping:type=ProcessingPing".

Can you confirm that this object name is actually the same as the one you can see in JConsole - the ObjectName row in the MBeanInfo section?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint. I used my client to list all the beans exposed, and saw that mine had "com.spmsoftware:name=ProcessingPing,product=optymyze" for name. I used it in the constructor for ObjectName and it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the objectname in mbean defined is different from the one you are providing in JMX client code.
The object name should match exactly as what you define in java class like in below class m bean is exposed by using spring.

Example - the below line written on top of class 
@ManagedResource(objectName = "com.spmsoftware.processing.ping:type=ProcessingPing"

Or you can also check in jconsole.exe and go to tab mbeans and check the name of mbean on left pane.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to create the Bean (in these case ProcessingPingImpl).

Annotation solution:
You can use `@Component` on the bean and `@ComponentScan("com.company")` on the @Configuration-Object. 
(see http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html)

Or you create the bean directly in the @Configuration-Object like this:

```
@Bean
public ProcessingPing processingPing(){
    return new ProcessingPingImpl();
}
```

XML solution:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />
```

(see in https://github.com/spring-by-example/spring-by-example/blob/master/enterprise/spring-jmx/src/test/resources/org/springbyexample/jmx/JmxTest-context.xml)

Or without component-scan:

```
<bean id="processingPing" class="com.company.ProcessingPingImpl" />
```